# Stop Gitconfig file from being overwritten by Local .git/config

Tags: git

recently I started using the includeIf functionality in my git config to handle multiple git user accounts for different projects, but I have a problem that is driving me crazy.

The includeIf part of the script seems to be overwriting the main git config file. Even if I'm not using the repo where it should be applied.

Here's my `.gitconfig`:

```
[user]
    name = Default Gitlab
    email = default.gitlab@project1.com
[includeIf "gitdir:~/repos/project2/"]
    path = ~/.gitconfig-github
```

And `.gitconfig-github`

```
[user]
    name = Another Github
    email = another.github@project2.com
```

The problem is that after a while my `.gitconfig` looks like this:

```
[user]
    name = Another Github
    email = another.github@project2.com
[includeIf "gitdir:~/repos/project2/"]
    path = ~/.gitconfig-github
```

I really can't figure out why or how this is happening.

Thanks for all your help!

```
########
# Edit #
########
```

I noticed is not exactly `includeIf` that is doing it.
The change seems to happen every time a change happens in my repo local git config.

Still trying to figure it out...

Comment: The global config file is only changed if you ask git to change it. My guess is that you are using a git-related tool that configures the username.

Comment: I would check out every tool you use that has some kind of git integration, try restoring the correct configuration, then using the tool, and then checking the file.